# Chrome Packaged app communication with webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have used chrome packaged app that Chrome-Serial-App-master 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/Chrome-Serial-App/blob/master/README.md)

```
Manifest
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "main.js"
        ]
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "serial"
]
```

I want to receive value from packaged app to my website at text box area
Can I access my webpage Dom ?
or use message passing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but you can use XMLHttpRequest to read the HTML of any webpage and then display that by setting the innerHTML property of some element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message passing. You can use chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal or chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal chrome APIs for this purpose.